# Why does the Noble Eightfold Path work?

Tags: philosophy

Since I have started reading Buddhist texts and trying to follow the Noble Eightfold Path, my life is happier and 'easier' **but why is this**? I believe it to be 'common sense' and the innate human nature that doing good is easier than doing bad but it can also be the reverse with certain conditions in this world. In a nutshell, I've taken the optimistic stance on this [philosophical debate](http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20130114-are-we-naturally-good-or-bad).

To understand the context of my question, let me describe my thought process on trying to understand this:

What if in our ultimate beginning (if there was one), we were all in an unconditioned state but then somehow became conditioned which lead to becoming (think of the story of Adam & Eve). Since this becoming, our ultimate objective is to return back to that unconditioned state and because we were in that unconditioned state, if one were to follow the Noble Eightfold path it would be innately/instinctively accepted to work.

I believe those that follow the path and through practice accept it to be logical but also to be innately/instinctively accepted. (Since this is a Buddhist forum, *I believe users here can agree on this opinion*).

**Question**: My question is based on the premise that the above is somewhat logical and in accordance with Buddhist teachings; if so is there any Buddhist literature that can elaborate on why it is ‘easier’ to follow the path or if its the total opposite. I believe ‘easier’ here can be subjective but I believe through my elementary understanding of Buddhist text, once you realize what is right in front of you; it is/can be easy.

If my logic is incorrect or you see a confusion in my question, please show me the correct way with references to Buddhist literature as well.

Comment: Please see [this question](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/26306/43) and my answer to it.

Comment: @AndreiVolkov thanks for the link. You’re right, removing conflict makes things a lot easier which by following the path is doing just that. In a way my question is a duplicate to the question in your link. Your answer fundamentally answers my question but does it go deeper? Reading your answer along with the others is logically sound and IMO instinctively correct but I guess the other part of my question is why is that? By asking why, am I just going in circular thinking?

Comment: The nature of suffering is conflict because mind (being an informational phenomenon) does not handle logical contradictions well. So anything that leads to an experience of clash or contradiction is perceived as suffering by the mind attached to (or identifying with) one of the sides of the contradiction. Conversely, reducing the conflict leads to experience of harmony, and that's the mechanism behind 8NP. This is already down at the level of fundamentals; I don't think there is a further why more fundamental than this.

Comment: Thanks Andrei, this answers my question in entirety. You can close this question.