# What's the different between kusala (good) and akusala (bad)?

Tags: abhidhamma, right-view, sila

What's the different between [ku-sala](http://accesstoinsight.eu/en/dictionary/kusala) (good) and [a-ku-sala](http://accesstoinsight.eu/en/dictionary/kusala) (bad), in regard of what the Buddha taught?

*(ku - bad, sala - cutting away, a - not)*

What are good and bad actions by deeds, speech and mind, and what qualities defines them as such?

`Here   he grieves
    he grieves  hereafter.
In both worlds
the wrong-doer grieves.
He grieves, he's afflicted,
seeing the corruption
    of his deeds.`

`Here   he rejoices
    he rejoices hereafter.
In both worlds
the merit-maker rejoices.
He rejoices, is jubilant,
seeing the purity
    of his deeds.`
[Yamakavagga](http://www.zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/kn/dhp/dhp.01.bpit_en.html#s-dhp-16)

So good to now really good of how to distinguish and alltime worthy to ask, remember and tell for many's benefit, and the own.

*(Note that this is not asked/given for trade, exchange, stacks or entertainment but as a means to escape this wheel here)*

Comment: This may be a duplicate of (or related to) [What determines whether actions are good or bad?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/1476/what-determines-whether-actions-are-good-or-bad)

Comment: It isn't and to delete things going against your grain does not change that but simply increases the akusala actions of your further.

Comment: The individual question> "What determines whether actions are good or bad?", really doesn't fit the question here. It would be good is that would be answered separate here

Answer (score 1):

The explanation for `Kusala` can be found in `MN-3 -> Maha Chattarika Sutta` ( I can't find this in english translation site, but this is in [Sinhala / Pali Thripitaka](https://pitaka.lk/main/?n=20117) ), So if I explain it how I understood by reading it,

It's about noble eightfold path, and in each it's describe two things one is `lokottara (= focusing on Nivana) path` the other one is `laukika (= focusing on good things in this world: eg -> samma kammanta = to do a decent job, not kill animals and sell`).

And the opposite of this is `Akusala` which doing opposite things not knowing what the `right` view, resolve, speech, etc..

About `lokottara path` that person should have a correct view what is the problem with the world, why we are attached to things, and why we should not attached, what's the danger in that so on.

Hope my description led some lights and I should accept that I'm not a good translator.

**Update:**
Found more information on this. It's in `Vibhangaprakaranaya-1, paticcasamuppada vibhangaya` There you can notice `what is kusala dharmayo`, the explanation is given the paticcasamuppada cycle but it starts with `sankara` not with `avijja` that means when a thought is processed without `avijja` it causes to Nivana as it is a `kusala`

Comment: English copies of MN 117 are [here](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.117.than.html) and [here](https://suttacentral.net/mn117).